# cannot click element in python via selenium as a variable

Tags: python, selenium

I want to save element data to an excel file via python. I have the code below, I need some help why the line where

```
element.click()
```

gives an error. Even though I put the click() method upper line, but i need it to be in line below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\chromedriver_win32 (1)\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
element_to_click=driver.find_element(By.ID,"onetrust-accept-btn-handler").click()
    element_to_click.click() 'error
element_to_save=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div/div/div/div/h4")
#element_to_save.to_excel("3row,3column)")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work because you assign the actual click() event to variable `element_to_click`. Then you try to click again on the .. event? of course, you get an error. Anyway, you have a better solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to reject/accept cookies on that website:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

url = 'https://www.nba.com/schedule?pd=false&region=1'
browser.get(url)
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
```

Setup is selenium/chrome on linux - just observe the imports and the part after defining the browser/driver.
Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: It does not close pop-window. I need to click 'Accept' button

Comment: @xlmaster I updated the code to accept the cookies now - it was a matter of changing the ID value.

Comment: Perfect!! works great! I liked your way.

Comment: @xlmaster Does this resolved your question? If so, why don't you accept the answer?

Comment: Believe me, I have similar thoughts... But you know, sometimes we can upvote people giving good answers here ;)

Comment: @Prophet - your answer to the Target question also works fine btw. :)

Comment: I know :) But the OP is ...

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus, hey I have seen your post about only selenium in python. Can you refer me a good book about it?

Comment: Which post, @xlmaster? I cannot really recommend any book, course, training. All I can recommend is - make sure your foundational understanding of programming are up to date, and then you build on that using whatever resource you can find. A lot of work and effort will get you there.